# How to insert an image onto a webpage using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am building a simple website and I am trying to get an image onto the page using Flask. All i get is the broken image symbol on the page tho.

Here is the server code...

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def homePage():
    return render_template("HomePage.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And here is HomePage.html...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>
</style>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img href="{{ url_for('static', filename='testing.png') }}" />
    </body>
</html>

<script>
</script>
```

My file structure is as followed...

```
-Web
     -static
          -testing.png
     -templates
          -HomePage.html
     server.py
```

Now, if i actually inspect through chrome, I can see the img tag gets converted to

```
<img href="/static/testing.png">
```

and if I right click this in chrome and open it in a new tab the image appears, But is still doesn't show on my web page.

Comment: What does the view-source say and what does the network tab say when you press F12

Comment: The view source has the img tag as follows... ` <img href="/static/testing.png" />` As for the network tab, it just has localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `img` tag use `src` attribute rather than `href` attribute.

In `HomePage.html` change the following line:

```
<img href="{{ url_for('static', filename='testing.png') }}" />
```

to

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='testing.png') }}" />
```

**Reference:**

- [MDN's documentation on img tag attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Attributes)